# dynamic url for specific primary key in Django

Tags: python, django, django-urls

My model has a field call `topic`, and I want to create a page which can show the specific, and the urls can be dynamic path to different topics rendered by the same html template. How do I suppose to do it?

models.py:

```
TOPIC = (
    (0,"Finance"),
    (1,"Toys"),
    (2,"Foods"),
    (3,"Travel"),
)

class Post(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, max_length=200)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='blog_posts')
    updated_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now= True)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    body = RichTextField(null=True)
    status = models.IntegerField(choices=STATUS, default=0)
    topic = models.IntegerField(choices=TOPIC, default=0)
    cover_img = models.ImageField(upload_to='post_cover', null=True, default='post_cover/coming_soon.jpg')

def __str__(self):
    return self.name

def get_img(self):
    return f"{'/media/post_cover/'+self.cover_img}"
```

html

```
<div class="col-md-6 mt-3 ">
     <a href="{% url 'topic_list' %}">
        <img src="../media/topic/travel3.jpg" alt=''>
     </a>
</div>
```

views.py

```
def topic_list(request):
    posts = Post.objects.filter(topic=0)
    context = {'posts': posts, 'autor_list':autor_list}
    return render(request, 'topic_list.html', context)
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views


urlpatterns = [
     path('', views.home, name='home'),
     path('topic/', views.topic_list, name='topic_list'),
     path('<slug:slug>/', views.post_detail, name='post_detail'),]
```

Comment: Are you asking 1) how to build URLs in the post_list template to each post or 2) how to make a correct URL pattern and a view for post_detail page?

Comment: actually I wamt to build a url for each topic of post list,  so I dont need to make 4 pages for those 4 topic,  just 1 dynamic url can go every topics

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To generate a *dynamic url* in the template use url-reversion function with arguments

```
{% for post in post_list %}
   <a href="{% url 'post_detail' post.slug %}">{{ post.name}}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

this will *reverse* `post_detail` url pattern from your urls.py with `post.slug` value passed to `'<slug:slug>/'`

If you need to list posts per topic then fix your url pattern and the view like below:

```
urlpatterns = [
     ...
     path('topic/<int:pk>/', views.topic_post_list, name='topic-posts-list'),
]

def topic_post_list(request, pk):
    posts = Post.objects.filter(topic_id=pk, )
    context = {'posts': posts, }
    return render(request, 'post_list.html', context)
```

Comment: what if I want to go to the post_list and filter the primary key by 'topic'? just like the hm_pg.html have a url can go to {% url 'post_list' pk=post.topic %}, the dynamic url for topic in models.py

Comment: You better fix your views and patterns names. If you want to see posts for particular topic - name it `topic_post_list` or something like that.

Comment: so what's next after I name it? how to go different topic post list by dynamic url?

Comment: In my code it is `topic-posts-list`, not `post_list`.